# Pyspark socket write error

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm trying to read the file(~600M *csv* file) with **pyspark.** But I get the following error.

Surprisingly the same code works correctly for **Scala**.

I found this issue page 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12261 but does not work.

Reading Code:

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

datasetDir = 'D:\\Datasets\\movieLens\\ml-latest\\'
ratingFile = 'ratings.csv'

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("movie_recommendation-server").setMaster('local[2]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

ratingRDD = sc.textFile(os.path.join(datasetDir, ratingFile))
print(ratingRDD.take(1)[0])
```

I am getting this error:

```
   
 16/04/25 09:00:04 ERROR PythonRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly    (crashed)
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
```